# When setting and getting session data with Socket.IO, what are passed functions for?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In the following code snippet taken from the Socket.IO website,

```
socket.set('nickname', name, function () {
    socket.emit('ready');
});
```

when setting client data, what's the passed function used for? Is it used simply to fire the function once the data is set? If so, what's the difference with:

```
socket.set('nickname', name);
socket.emit('ready');
```

Also what is `err` used for in the following:

```
socket.get('nickname', function (err, name) {
    console.log('Chat message by ', name);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when setting client data, what's the passed function used for

That's an async callback, which means it's a function that will be called after the `set` operation was completed

> If so, what's the difference with...

It's a big difference. `socket.set` is non-blocking, which means the method will be called but the process will continue with the following code, without waiting for it to finish. This means the `socket.emit` will be called before the `set` was completed.

> Also what is 'err' used for in the following:

err can be a connection error or anything that went wrong during the `get` method